# Merge all lines that are identical aside from a key field and make key field a range

Tags: bash, merge, scripting, combine

I've been looking at a lot of posts and haven't quite found what I'm looking for. I'm not sure how to go about taking the following sample data:

```
host1   input   nic1    ip1 ip2 PROT    30000   10
host1   input   nic1    ip1 ip2 PROT    40000   10
host1   input   nic1    ip1 ip2 PROT    50000   10
host1   input   nic1    ip1 ip2 PROT    60000   10
host1   input   nic1    ip3 ip2 PROT    10      30000
host1   input   nic1    ip3 ip2 PROT    10      40000
host1   input   nic1    ip3 ip2 PROT    10      50000
host1   input   nic1    ip3 ip2 PROT    10      60000
host1   output  nic1    ip2 ip1 PROT    10      30000
host1   output  nic1    ip2 ip1 PROT    10      40000
host1   output  nic1    ip2 ip1 PROT    10      50000
host1   output  nic1    ip2 ip1 PROT    10      60000
host1   output  nic1    ip2 ip3 PROT    30000   10
host1   output  nic1    ip2 ip3 PROT    40000   10
host1   output  nic1    ip2 ip3 PROT    50000   10
host1   output  nic1    ip2 ip3 PROT    60000   10
host1   output  loc     ip2 ip2 PROT    10      30000
host1   output  loc     ip2 ip2 PROT    10      50000
```

And merge it into:

```
host1   input   nic1    ip1 ip2 PROT    30000:60000 10
host1   input   nic1    ip3 ip2 PROT    10          30000:60000
host1   output  nic1    ip2 ip1 PROT    10          30000:60000
host1   output  nic1    ip2 ip3 PROT    30000:60000 10
host1   output  loc     ip2 ip2 PROT    10          30000:50000
```

I have a large amount of data like this with the need to make ranges for multiple fields of a given line but I think if somebody can show me how to do it for one field as I have above, I should be able to figure the rest out. And if not I'll follow up :). Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: When you say *large amount of data* is that larger than fits into memory?

Comment: `datamash groupby 1,2,3,4,5,6 min 7 max 7 min 8 max 8 < file`?

Comment: @dawg sorry I am only talking about a few hundred MBs of text files, so memory isn't an issue

Comment: @oguzismail I will datamash but I really need something native to linux like the awk scripts offered up so far.  Thank you very much for the suggestion.

Comment: @oguzismail Thanks for the introduction to datamash!  It did output results very close to what I need but sadly I need a solutions not requiring installation of additional software in Linux

Answer (score 4):

### Update

I have refactored the code in the answer below so as to make it more readable. The main body should read almost English prose.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
# main body
NR == 1 {
  copyRecordTo(veryold)
  next
}
{
  if (inSameGroup()) {
    copyRecordTo(old)
  } else {
    makeRangeForField(NF - 1)
    makeRangeForField(NF)
    nicePrint()
    copyRecordTo(veryold)
  }
}
END {
  makeRangeForField(NF - 1)
  makeRangeForField(NF)
  nicePrint()
}

# functions
function copyRecordTo(line) {
  for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) line[i] = $i
}
function nicePrint() {
  for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) {
    i == NF - 1 ? fmt = "%s\t\t" : fmt = "%s\t"
    printf(fmt, old[i])
  }
  printf("\n")
}
function makeRangeForField(f) {
  if (old[f] != veryold[f])
    old[f] = veryold[f]":"old[f]
}
function inSameGroup() {
  b = 1
  for (i = 1; i <= NF - 2; ++i)
    b *= $i == veryold[i]
  return b == 1
}
```

### Original answer

The following `awk` script generates almost what you are looking for.

Essentially the script does the following:

- stores in `veryold` the first line of each set of lines that differ only for the 7th and/or 8th filed
- stores in `old` the last read line
- the "boolean" `b` is used to check when that last line is surpassed
- when this happens the last two fields of `veryold` are joined with those of `old` with a `:` in between if they are different, and `old` is printed
- one more tab `\t` is used between the last two fields to improve readability

Other two points:

- `NR == 1` is a special case that has to initialize `veryold` only
- after the last line is read `END` handles the special case of the last line stored in `old`

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
NR == 1 {
  for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i) {
    veryold[i] = $i
  }
  next
}
{
  b = 1
  for (i = 2; i <= NF - 2; ++i) {
    b *= $i == veryold[i]
  }
  if (b == 1) {
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) {
      old[i] = $i
    }
  } else {
    if (old[NF - 1] != veryold[NF - 1]) {
      old[NF - 1] = veryold[NF - 1]":"old[NF - 1]
    }
    if (old[NF] != veryold[NF]) {
      old[NF] = veryold[NF]":"old[NF]
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) {
      if (i == NF - 1) {
        fmt = "%s\t\t"
      } else {
        fmt = "%s\t"
      }
      printf(fmt, old[i])
    }
    printf("\n")
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i) {
      veryold[i] = $i
    }
  }
}
END {
  if (old[NF - 1] != veryold[NF - 1]) {
    old[NF - 1] = veryold[NF - 1]":"old[NF - 1]
  }
  if (old[NF] != veryold[NF]) {
    old[NF] = veryold[NF]":"old[NF]
  }
  for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) {
    if (i == NF - 1) {
      fmt = "%s\t\t"
    } else {
      fmt = "%s\t"
    }
    printf(fmt, old[i])
  }
}
```

Comment: Lovely masterpiece of an `awk` script here. Just mentioning alternate shebang with `env` to execute the `awk` interpreter regardless of its path: `#!/usr/bin/env --split-string awk --file` or short form: `#!/usr/bin/env -S awk -f`

Comment: @LéaGris I think this script is overcomplicated, but it's what I can come with at 1AM. Concerning the shebang, isn't it limited to have only one argument?

Comment: The `env --split-string` See: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/env.1.html#OPTIONS `-S/--split-string usage in scripts: The -S option allows specifying multiple parameters in a script. Running a script named 1.pl containing the following first line: #!/usr/bin/env -S perl -w -T`. So it passes any number of space delimited arguments to the interpreter.

Comment: In the `NR == 1` rule, you can add `next` as the final command and then remove the `NR > 1` condition. (regardless -- well done)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, thanks! I have also refactored the code to make it more readable (at least I find it more readable).

Comment: @LéaGris, this seems great! However I really want to know more about it, so I have posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60900242/how-to-pass-multiple-parameters-to-the-shebang-as-of-today).

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis Thanks so much for your help so far, this was close but did have some oddities in terms of results.

Comment: @juggy_gales, _oddities_? Please, be more specific.