# How to pass multiple parameters to the shebang as of today

Tags: shebang

The last time I searched for it I concluded it's not possible, or at least not portable, so I gave up and forgot.

However, in a comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60895970/5825294) I posted, I was suggested to check [`env`'s `man` page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/env.1.html#OPTIONS), which contains the following

> ```
>    -S, --split-string=S
>           process and split S into separate arguments;
>           used to pass multiple arguments on shebang lines
> ```

Searching for *"multiple parameters" shebang* only finds 3 results, and none of those mentions this option.

What is state of this topic at the moment in terms of support and portability?