# Bash or Awk Script to Merge Lines Where X Number of Fields Match While Creating Ranges in Fields that Don't Match

Tags: linux, bash, awk, scripting

**NEED**:  I have a file containing data like the sample below.  I need to:

1. Merge all lines into one line when X number of fields match
2. Create range of values in X number of fields when the values vary

*In this case:
Merge all lines into one where **fields $1 through $6 and $8 match**, create a range of the associated values in field **$7***

OR

Merge all lines into one where **fields $1 through $7** match, create a range of the associated values in field **$8***

3. The solution has to be something native to Linux (like a bash or awk script) that doesn't require installation of additional software (e.g. datamash).

*@rtx13's solution below using TCL does work (thanks again), I'm just not sure if I can install TCL in my live environment so I hope and AWK/BASH/etc. solution can also be proposed.*

**Original data:**

```
HOST    FILTER  INTERFACE   SOURCE  DESTINATION PROTOCOL    SOURCE PORT DESTINATION PORT
host1   input   nic1        ip1     ip2         PROT        30000       10
host1   input   nic1        ip1     ip2         PROT        50000       10
host1   input   nic1        ip1     ip2         PROT        60000       10
host1   input   nic1        ip3     ip2         PROT        10          30000
host1   input   nic1        ip3     ip2         PROT        10          50000
host1   input   nic1        ip3     ip2         PROT        10          60000
host1   output  nic1        ip2     ip1         PROT        10          30000
host1   output  nic1        ip2     ip1         PROT        10          50000
host1   output  nic1        ip2     ip1         PROT        10          60000
host1   output  nic1        ip2     ip3         PROT        30000       10
host1   output  nic1        ip2     ip3         PROT        60000       10
host1   output  loc         ip2     ip2         PROT        10          30000
host1   output  loc         ip2     ip2         PROT        10          50000
```

**Desired Processed Output:**

```
host1   input   nic1        ip1     ip2         PROT        30000:60000 10
host1   input   nic1        ip3     ip2         PROT        10          30000:60000
host1   output  nic1        ip2     ip1         PROT        10          30000:60000
host1   output  nic1        ip2     ip3         PROT        30000:60000 10
host1   output  loc         ip2     ip2         PROT        10          30000:50000
```

Do I need a separate file that lists the ports I'd like to merge on?  Since these could also fall inside a range as well?  So the script could reference it to know whether it's a merge port or not?

```
10|EXAMPLE
22|SSH
80|HTTP
2049|NFS
*etc*
```

I'm trying to be as specific as I can be since my original post was deemed to need more focus; it received an answer (Thanks you @Enrico Maria De Angelis) that was close, but not quite all the way there as well as one that used datamash (Thank you @oguz ismail), which worked great but sadly I need a solution not requiring installation of additonal software:
[Merge all lines that are identical aside from a key field and make key field a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60895489/merge-all-lines-that-are-identical-aside-from-a-key-field-and-make-key-field-a-r)

Comment: Can you clarify the merge requirement?  It looks like you also need _Merge all lines into one where fields $1 through $6 and $7 match, create a range of the associated values in field $8_ ...

Comment: @rtx13 Argh, sorry this is my first time trying to post something! You're correct, there are two scenarios where a merge is required.  I've updated my post with the second scenario.

Comment: @rtx13 Your comment also has me thinking I need to have a separate file maybe, that lists the specific ports I want to merge on?

Comment: No problem, just want to understand the scope of the problem.  Do you happen to have `tcl` available on the system that needs to run this code?  You can check by running `tclsh` from your shell/terminal.

Comment: @rtx13 It doesn't currently have tcl installed, however it does look like it's available straight from Redhat so it's possible I could pull it from my local repo.

Comment: One more clarification:  are the merged ports _ranges_ or _lists_?  Given 3 otherwise matching rows of with unique values of 60000, 30000, 40000, do you expect 30000:60000, or 60000:30000:40000?

Comment: @rtx13 Ah, yes good question.  30000:60000 is what I'd need to see.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210628/discussion-between-rtx13-and-juggy-gales).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works on both columns.  Provide the list of ports to merge on via command line.

---

`mergecolumn2` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh

# read data in and store into 'output' array and 'row_key' list
set rows [lrange [split [read -nonewline stdin] "\n"] 1 end]
foreach row $rows {
    if { [lsearch -exact $argv [lindex $row 6]] >= 0 } {
        set merge_column 7
    } elseif { [lsearch -exact $argv [lindex $row 7]] >= 0 } {
        set merge_column 6
    } else {
        set merge_column -1 ;# do not merge
    }
    if { $merge_column >= 0 } {
        set value [lindex $row $merge_column]
        set row [lreplace $row $merge_column $merge_column "%s"]
    } else {
        set value ""
        set row [list {*}$row] ;# trim spaces for consistency
    }
    if { ![info exist output($row)] } {
        lappend row_key $row
    }
    lappend output($row) $value
}

# iterate over 'row_key' and generate output
foreach row $row_key {
    if { [llength $output($row)] > 1 } {
        set o [lreplace [lsort -dictionary $output($row)] 1 end-1]
    } else {
        set o $output($row)
    }
    puts [format $row [join $o :]]
}
```

---

Terminal session:

```sh
$ ./mergecolumn2 < data
host1 input nic1 ip1 ip2 PROT 30000 10
host1 input nic1 ip1 ip2 PROT 50000 10
host1 input nic1 ip1 ip2 PROT 60000 10
host1 input nic1 ip3 ip2 PROT 10 30000
host1 input nic1 ip3 ip2 PROT 10 50000
host1 input nic1 ip3 ip2 PROT 10 60000
host1 output nic1 ip2 ip1 PROT 10 30000
host1 output nic1 ip2 ip1 PROT 10 50000
host1 output nic1 ip2 ip1 PROT 10 60000
host1 output nic1 ip2 ip3 PROT 30000 10
host1 output nic1 ip2 ip3 PROT 60000 10
host1 output loc ip2 ip2 PROT 10 30000
host1 output loc ip2 ip2 PROT 10 50000
$ ./mergecolumn2 10 22 80 2049 < data
host1 input nic1 ip1 ip2 PROT 30000:60000 10
host1 input nic1 ip3 ip2 PROT 10 30000:60000
host1 output nic1 ip2 ip1 PROT 10 30000:60000
host1 output nic1 ip2 ip3 PROT 30000:60000 10
host1 output loc ip2 ip2 PROT 10 30000:50000
$
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works on one column at a time.

---

`mergecolumn` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh
# check for column number
if { ![llength $argv] || ![regexp {^\d+$} [lindex $argv 0] merge_column] } {
    puts stderr "usage: $argv0 column (0-based)"
    exit 1
}

# read data in and store into 'output' array and 'row_key' list
set rows [lrange [split [read -nonewline stdin] "\n"] 1 end]
foreach row $rows {
    set value [lindex $row $merge_column]
    set row [lreplace $row $merge_column $merge_column "%s"]
    if { ![info exist output($row)] } {
        lappend row_key $row
    }
    lappend output($row) $value
}

# iterate over 'row_key' and generate output
foreach row $row_key {
    if { [llength $output($row)] > 1 } {
        set o [lreplace [lsort -dictionary $output($row)] 1 end-1]
    } else {
        set o $output($row)
    }
    puts [format $row [join $o :]]
}
```

---

Terminal session:

```sh
$ cat data
HOST    FILTER  INTERFACE   SOURCE  DESTINATION PROTOCOL    SOURCE PORT DESTINATION PORT
host1   input   nic1        ip1     ip2         PROT        30000       10
host1   input   nic1        ip1     ip2         PROT        50000       10
host1   input   nic1        ip1     ip2         PROT        60000       10
host1   input   nic1        ip3     ip2         PROT        10          30000
host1   input   nic1        ip3     ip2         PROT        10          50000
host1   input   nic1        ip3     ip2         PROT        10          60000
host1   output  nic1        ip2     ip1         PROT        10          30000
host1   output  nic1        ip2     ip1         PROT        10          50000
host1   output  nic1        ip2     ip1         PROT        10          60000
host1   output  nic1        ip2     ip3         PROT        30000       10
host1   output  nic1        ip2     ip3         PROT        60000       10
host1   output  loc         ip2     ip2         PROT        10          30000
host1   output  loc         ip2     ip2         PROT        10          50000
$ ./mergecolumn 6 < data
host1 input nic1 ip1 ip2 PROT 30000:60000 10
host1 input nic1 ip3 ip2 PROT 10 30000
host1 input nic1 ip3 ip2 PROT 10 50000
host1 input nic1 ip3 ip2 PROT 10 60000
host1 output nic1 ip2 ip1 PROT 10 30000
host1 output nic1 ip2 ip1 PROT 10 50000
host1 output nic1 ip2 ip1 PROT 10 60000
host1 output nic1 ip2 ip3 PROT 30000:60000 10
host1 output loc ip2 ip2 PROT 10 30000
host1 output loc ip2 ip2 PROT 10 50000
$ ./mergecolumn 7 < data
host1 input nic1 ip1 ip2 PROT 30000 10
host1 input nic1 ip1 ip2 PROT 50000 10
host1 input nic1 ip1 ip2 PROT 60000 10
host1 input nic1 ip3 ip2 PROT 10 30000:60000
host1 output nic1 ip2 ip1 PROT 10 30000:60000
host1 output nic1 ip2 ip3 PROT 30000 10
host1 output nic1 ip2 ip3 PROT 60000 10
host1 output loc ip2 ip2 PROT 10 30000:50000
$
```

Comment: OP was ok with TCL.  See comments and chat under Question.

Comment: Thanks so much for the tcl script.  I'm still not sure if i can install tcl in my environment but using this on a test system works like a charm.  Very nice job!

Comment: @juggy_gales Happy to help. If this or any other answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.  To accept an answer, click the check mark button (✓) underneath the vote buttons.